# call a function so that it runs in the context of the main function in mpi?

Tags: c++, mpi

I want to call a function when using `MPI`, usually, the function would run on each process independently, so I have to split the data in the main function.

But what if I want the code in the called function run like it is in the context of the main(), so I could split the data to each process in the code of the called function.

How should I do that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mpi.h>


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
  int world_rank;
  MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);
  int world_size;
  MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

  // For each process, call a function
  // the following code run on each process independently
  do_some_stuff();
  // what if I want the code in do_some_stuff() runs like it is in the context 
  // of the main()

  MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  MPI_Finalize();
}

// A function
void do_some_stuff() {
  //the following code run on each process independently
  int a = 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve and what you mean by "context"? if you simply want to "split" the data and compute in `do_some_stuff()`, then simply do so.

Comment: When executing a command `mpirun -n nb_MPI_proc my_exe my_args`, it'll run nb_MPI_proc processes, each with it's own PID, equivalent to if you have execute the command `my_exec my_args` nb_MPI_proc times (eventually on different machines but not necessarily). So if you want each process to have a part of the data then your function `do_some_stuff()` should load only the data for the MPI proc that executes it. Otherway to say it, you have to it yes 